# Aurora read replica writer instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have an rds instance and it has an aurora read replica.

I only use that as a read replica to run report-type queries against; and use aurora’s SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 feature to write the report query data to s3. Otherwise I could just have a standard rds instance as my read replica, but I want the SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 feature.

When I create an Aurora read replica the cluster comes with a writer instance and a reader instance.

Is it safe to delete the writer instance from the cluster leaving only the reader instance?

I only use this for select queries. I have no intention to promote this cluster to become the primary DB. And having a read replica marked as “writer instance” is just confusing and asking for trouble.

Comment: If you delete the writer instance, the reader will be promoted to writer.